# Sci-fi novel where a mother and son are captured by another tribe

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic, soft-sci-fi

This was a sci-fi novel I read decades ago.

Most of the story takes place after a mother and her son have been captured by another tribe and are being transported back to their encampment. I believe one or both die in the end. I believe there are anachronistic things in the world that lead me to believe it was a post-apocalyptic setting.

Comment: This is very brief can you remember any of the plot elements besides what you've mentioned as at the moment this likely matches several works? Why were they captured and taken to another tribe? You say tribe, is this like an Amazonian tribe or something more advanced? You say sci-fi novel but nothing here is science fictional, can you remember any actual sci-fi elements? Maybe the transport? Was that by spaceship? You also say decades ago, roughly how many? i.e. what year would that have been approx?

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Could it be Dune?

Comment: Can you remember any details at all? Even the smallest detail can help jog our memories.